# ¿Cuàl es mi error al intentar mostrar esta gràfica con Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Soy bastante nuevo en Chart.js y he intentado muchas formas diferentes de hacerlo, pero parece que no puedo resolver la carga de datos de *JSON* en un gráfico de tipo de barra.

Estoy tratando de mostrar una tabla de porcentajes de avance de los *estudiantes* que luego tendrè que agrupar si està inscrito en màs cursos, con la última versión de Chart.js.

La cadena *JSON* es la siguiente:

```
[{"curso_id":"4","curso_nombre":"Test","nombre":"Estudiante","ap_p":"A_P","usuario_id":"2","total_temas":"7","temas_vistos":"3","porcentaje":"42.8571"},{"curso_id":"5","curso_nombre":"Excel","nombre":"Estudiante","ap_p":"A_P","usuario_id":"2","total_temas":"2","temas_vistos":"2","porcentaje":"100.0000"}]
```

Pero sigue mostrando *undefined* y no me muestra ningùn otro error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var chartColors ={
            red: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            blue: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            orange: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            darkgrey: 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)',
            maroon: 'rgba(200, 112, 91, 1)',
            khaki: 'rgba(190, 204, 200, 1)'
                     };

                    $.ajax({ 
                        url:'../graficas/contAvance.php',
                        method: "GET",
                        success: function(data){
                                var nombre = [];
                                var porcentaje = [];

                                for (var i in data){
                                        nombre.push(data[i].nombre);
                                        porcentaje.push(data[i].porcentaje);
                                    }
                                var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart2").getContext('2d');
                                        var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
                                            type: 'bar',
                                            data: {
                                                labels: nombre,
                                                datasets: [{
                                                    label: 'Porcentaje',
                                                    backgroundColor: 
                                                        [
                                                            chartColors.red

                                                        ],
                                                    borderColor: 
                                                    [

                                                        chartColors.orange
                                                    ],
                                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                                    data: porcentaje
                                                }]
                                            },

                                            options:{
                                                responsive: true,
                                                maintainAspectRatio: false,

                                                legend: {
                                                          display: false
                                                        },

                                                         ticks: {
                                                            beginAtZero:true,

                                                         }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                            },
                             error: function() {
        alert("There is a problem with loading the chart!");
    }

                         });                        
                })
```